# Gibbs entropy maximization confusion with Grand Canonical Ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

I'm trying to review some statistical mechanics from the following [link](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/%7Emevans/sp/sp2.pdf)

In doing so on the topic of variational theory and maximization with Lagrange multipliers, the author states that given a function:

$$
h(x_i) = f(x_i) - \lambda g(x_i),
$$

then to extremize we require the condition:

$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i} = 0.
$$

Though this is phrased a little differently than I am used to, the conclusion is the same and so I am okay with it.

However, later on the author solves this example with the case of a Grand Canonical Ensemble (GCE). In my own understanding, the GCE is described by the number of particles, and the energy. I arrived at the same constrain equations as the author however, based on my understanding the the parameteres of the same are described by $(E,N)$, I would have expected that there should have been two equations set to equal zero:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial E_n} \left[S - \lambda_E \sum P(E,N) E - \lambda_N \sum P(E,N) N - \lambda_1 \sum P(E,N) \right] = 0,
$$
and

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial N_n} \left[S - \lambda_E \sum P(E,N) E - \lambda_N \sum P(E,N) N - \lambda_1 \sum P(E,N) \right] = 0.
$$

I was able to find another text that arrives at the same solutions for the probability function, with different variable substitutions (in terms of $\mu$ and $\beta$) so I presume that this procedure is the correct one. I suspect my confusion is related to idea of: *what is a function of what*. Which has been a bane of my existence through all of my courses on thermodynamics and statistical mechanics.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: *should be pi and E and N should be $E_i$ and $N_i$* ... In the Link(https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~mevans/sp/sp2.pdf) they have for  Grand Canonical Ensemble (GCE) not $p_i$, but $p_{i,N}$ and so not $N_i$ but $N$ (see (12) at p.8)

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist You're right, I did not look at the author's notation, so I removed my comment to not add another layer of confusion ;) . (I prefer to sum over microstates $i$ with no constraints on the particle number and consider an observable $i\mapsto N_i$, which is of course equivalent. The author seems to prefer to sum over $N$ and over microstates with $N$ particles. This amount to the same thing, of course.)

Comment: @YvanVelenik I assume your previous comment is still correct with respect to the other details you mentioned? I.e I was confusing the prefered variables in the GCE, which should be $\mu,\beta$ not $E,N$?

Comment: If so am I correct in the following logic: We are taking derivatives with respect to $\mu,\beta$. In each microstate $N_i,E_i$ are constant because they are fixed for that microstate. Only the probability has a dependence on $\mu,\beta$, so although we are taking derivatives w.r.t $\mu,\beta$ this is equivalent to just considering derivatives of $p_i$? since this is equal to zero

Comment: Yes, the variables are $\mu$ and $\beta$ (although the identification of these constants with the Lagrange mutipliers should be done separately). Derivatives w.r.t. $\lambda_E$ and $\lambda_N$ (and  $\lambda_1$) will just yield the three constraints (normalization, fixed expected energy, fixed expected number of particles).

Comment: The derivatives w.r.t. $p_i$ (or rather $p_{Ni}$ in the notation of your reference) will lead to an equation determining the $p_i$: $\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i} \bigl(\sum_i p_i\log p_i - \lambda_E \sum_i p_i E_i - \lambda_N \sum_i p_i N_i - \lambda_1 \sum_i p_i \bigr) = 0 $ yields $\log p_i + 1 - \lambda_E E_i -\lambda_N N_i - \lambda_1 = 0$, that is, $p_i \propto \exp(\lambda_E E_i + \lambda_N N_i)$ as you want. You still have to argue that $\lambda_E = -\beta$ and $\lambda_N = \beta\mu$ if you wish to obtain the usual form, of course.

Comment: We discuss this in detail in Section 1.2 of [our book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook). (See also Section 1.3 for the link between the Lagrange multipliers and the relevant physical quantities.)

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot. The explanation in the textbook for connecting the Lagrange multipliers to physical quantities may be a bit above my reading level, but the explanation of getting probability function in terms of the multipliers makes much more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three constraints in the grand canonical ensemble:
$$ \sum_{n,j} a(n,j) = \mathcal{N} $$
$$ \sum_{n,j} a(n,j) E_j= \mathcal{N} \bar{E} $$
$$ \sum_{n,j} a(n,j) N_n= \mathcal{N} \bar{N} $$
$a(n,j)$ represents the number of samples with $N_n$ particles and energy $E_j$ in the giant canonical ensemble. $\mathcal{N}$ is the total number of samples. $w=\dfrac{\mathcal{N}!}{\Pi_{n,j}a(n,j)!}$ is the total number of microstates.
When we use the Lagrangian method, the function that needs to be constructed is:
$$f({a(n,j),\alpha,\beta, \gamma} = \ln w -\alpha ( \sum_{n,j} a(n,j) - \mathcal{N} )-\beta( \sum_{n,j} a(n,j) E_j - \mathcal{N} \bar{E} ) - \gamma (\sum_{n,j} a(n,j) N_n-\mathcal{N} \bar{N}) $$
The independent variables of the function f are only $ a(n,j),\alpha,\beta, \gamma $. 
$ \bar{E}, \bar{N}$ is the expectation of the number of particles and energy given in advance, $E_j, N_n$ is our artificial standard, such as $N_n$ must be $0,1,2,3...$ so they are constants rather than self-energy, and there is no need to take partial derivatives for them.